# Prove that $4^n$ is not divisible by 3.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

> How can one prove that $4^n$ is not divisible by 3, for any $n \ge 0$?

One way I found is to proof that  $4^n - 1$ is always divisible by 3 (as demonstrated in a question here), thus $4^n$ could never be divisible by 3.

Can you suggest a better way to prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use that $3$ is prime, that is $3\mid ab$ implies $3\mid a$ or $3\mid b$

Comment: *Prove* is the verb, *proof* is the noun.

Comment: $4^n$ is all $4$s and there ain't no $3$ in $4$.

Comment: I am guessing you want a proof without the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic which would make this proof trivial, as some of the answers below implicitly assume it. If that's the case, orion's answer is probably along the lines of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11):

If $3$ divides $4^n=2^{2n}$ it would appear in the latter's factorisation into primes.

Comment: Another classical Jasper Loy LHF :)

Comment: @Arkamis It annoys me how much votes he gets for just these one-liners!

Answer (score 11):

$$4=1\mod 3$$
and therefore
$$4^n=1\mod 3$$
That's it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the fact that if a prime divides a product, then it must divide a single term in the product.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $4^n=(2^2)^n=2^{2n}$ and $3$ is not a factor of $2^{2n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The prime factors of $4^n$ is the multiset $\{(2, 2n)\}$ and $3 \not \in \{(2, 2n)\}$.

Comment: The prime factor of $4^n$ is $2$. Multiset...?

Comment: Prime factorization is usually best thought of as a multiset of primes.

Comment: Oh, you mean $2$ with multiplicty $2n$. Well, that things is just a set. =P

Comment: A set has unique elements. You need a multiset to keep multiple copies of the same element.